# Apache Camel: Process file line by line

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-ftp

I have a large file that I want to read and process. I don't want to load it entirely into memory and instead of this I read each line of the file separately and perform actions on it. I've come to this implementation during the work:

```java
@Override
public void configure() {
    from(fileSftpLocationUrl)
        .routeId("my-route")
        .onException(Exception.class).handled(true).bean(exchangeErrorHandler, "processError").end()
        .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
        .filter(/*condition for skip first and last line*/)
        .bean(/*my action*/)
        .to(String.format("activemq:%s", myQueue));
}
```

Before starting to read the file I skip header and footer `.filter(/*condition for skip first and last line*/)` on that and in the next line I try to start reading my file line by line `.split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()` but something is going wrong and I get all information from the file in its entirety. I see that problem in the `.bean(/*my action*/)` when parsing that data and perform actions on them.

I think that my problem is hidden at the beginning because the algorithm looks strange, first I describe the condition for the whole file (skip header and footer), then I ask Camel to process it line by line, and only then the action for a specific line.

My question is, how do I change this implementation so that the file is processed line by line?

Comment: In windows, the line seperator is ``\r\n`` and in linux its ``\n``. Can that be a problem? You can use ``System.lineSeparator()`` instead to make is OS independent.

Comment: is the file CSV?

Comment: Don't you need to filter the lines *AFTER* (rather than before) having split them into n individual msg ? First split, then filter

Comment: > Hello @pratap.Thanks for your comment. The separator is fine. I'm sure that's not the point.
> Hello @BSangappa. No. it's. It's a simple `.txt` file but looks like `.csv` and content separated into columns by the `|` symbol.
> Hello @TacheDeChoco. Yes, sorry. My bad. I made an error when copy-pasting my code. In my implementation, I do filler after the split. I fixed the code in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it.
By default, the split result is sent to the **FIRST** next endpoint

```
from(...)
    .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
    .to("direct:processLine")
```

If you want to send it to a complex routing, you have to mark the split ending, eg

```
from(...)
       
     .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
        .filter(/*condition for skip first and last line*/)
        .bean(/*my action*/)
        .to(String.format("activemq:%s", myQueue))
     .end()
     .log("Split done");
```

If you omit the end(), the logic will be this one (see indentation):

```
from(...)
       
     .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
        .filter(/*condition for skip first and last line*/)
     .end() // Implicit 
     .bean(/*my action*/)
     .to(String.format("activemq:%s", myQueue))
```

-> in your attempt, the bean(...) was invoked with the original message (after the split was performed)

See it like a kind of "for-loop"

```
for (String line: lines) 
filter(line);
bean.run(line);
sendto(...);
```

is not the same at all as:

```
for (String line: lines) {
  filter(line);
  bean.run();
  sendto(...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @TacheDeChoco I think the last variant is my because it looks logical when we `end()` specific file operations and after it we do specific operations on file lines. But it's broke my filter: https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/b07c83bf

Comment: You have to take the variant with the `bean(...)` **inside** the split, so that the filtered split items will be sent to the bean. https://pastebin.pl/view/d298ff2d